# Is this a valid proof? (epsilon delta)

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm asked to prove using an $\epsilon - \delta$ - argument that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac { 4x^3 +  8xy^2}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}}  = 0  $. Here is the proof I came up with:

---

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then:

$\left|\dfrac { 4x^3 +  8xy^2}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}}\right| = \dfrac {\left|x\right| \left| 4x^2 +  8y^2 \right|}{\left|3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}\right|} \le \dfrac {\left|x\right| \left| 8x^2 +  8y^2 \right|}{\left|3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}\right|} = \dfrac {8\left|x\right|  (x^2 +  y^2)}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}} = \dfrac {8 \sqrt{x^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)}} \le\dfrac {8 \sqrt{x^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}  =\dfrac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Choose $\delta = \left(\dfrac{3}{8}\epsilon\right)^3$. Then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta \implies x < \delta \implies \dfrac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{x} < \dfrac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{\delta} = \epsilon $. So:

$\left|\dfrac { 4x^3 +  8xy^2}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)^4}}\right| < \epsilon$

---

Is this a valid proof? I am not very comfortable with the inequalities in these kind of proofs so I might have made a mistake there.

Comment: Looks good. 2 minor points: after the last equality in the first step, you should have $\frac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{|x|}$. Similarly, in the second step, you should work with $|x|$ instead of $x$. Be careful also that your working assumption is that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$. You need the left inequality to justify one of your simplifications.

Comment: When there is a relative of $x^2+y^2$ at the bottom, switching to polar is often useful.

Comment: @KimJongUn Thank you for your help! I see now that it should be |x| instead of x and i should use the because of how the definition of limit is. But I'm not sure where i would need the left side in the equalities/inequalities. My guess would be for $\dfrac {8 \sqrt{x^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{(x^2 + y^2)}} \le\dfrac {8 \sqrt{x^2}}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$.

Comment: @ OP: you need the assumption $x^2+y^2>0$ when you divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2+y^2$.